# idangerous swiper JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've only came across with idangerous JS plugin and when the load page it doesn't load the function. Though the other carousel swiper works okay.

```
        <div class="feedhead news clearfix">News</div>
        <div class="newscol-items swiper-wrapper">
            <?php
            //Instead do this using a WP Query and loop.
            $queryargs = array(
                'post_type'=>'news',
                'showposts'=>5
            );
            query_posts($queryargs);
            if (have_posts()){
                $count = 0;
                while (have_posts()) {
                    the_post();
                    $count++;
                    get_template_part('content','news');
                }
            } else {
                get_template_part('content','noposts');
            }
            wp_reset_query();
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

     <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(function(){
         // Tries to initialise the slider before the page has loaded
         var mySwiper2 = jQuery('.swiper-container.newscol').swiper({
             slideClass: 'post-item',
             slidesPerView: 4,
             slidesPerViewFit: false,
             loop: true,
             centeredSlides: true,
             autoplay: 5000,
             speed: 500,
             calculateHeight: true,
             roundLength: true,
             mode: 'horizontal'
         }); 
      });
      </script>
```

I checked the console log and its showing "***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getWidth' of undefined***". The function works when entered on the console.

Comment: Fixed it with window.onload.

Comment: Anyone knows about the getWidth error?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem and solved it by setting explicitly the width in pixels of the slide elements.

You can do that either with css:

```
.swiper-slide{
    width: 300px; /*change as what width suits you*/    
}
```

Or with js, right before initializing the swiper.

Consider that you need to follow the given html structure, shown in section "Swiper Full HTML Layout", in this link http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php

Comment: tried this kinda work but there is like an excess text/image on the sides. Only showing 5 posts, and images are set to max-width:100%, swiper-slide: 253px so shouldn't be any excess :/

Answer (score 0):

The container must have a exact width like 1170 px or 100% if the parent got a exact width OR fullscreen width and responsive. And ofcourse a height in px:

```
.swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

The Wrapper will not be touched in css.

The Slide only got the following css:

```
.swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;

    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

All elements IN the Swiper-slide like div li usw. must have 100% width to automatically get the correct width from the plugin.